# Setting Affinity of an Application on cmd

Tags: cmd, affinity

I have this problem when I'm using Voicemeeter and Discord together, my voice is just crackling and cutting out. I found out the solution to this problem. It's by going to the task manager, heading to details, right clicking audiodg.exe, and then setting it's affinity to only one processer. The problem is I don't want to do this all by hand everytime I start my computer. Is there any way I can write a line of code into the cmd that changes this? This way I can save this lane as a bat file and then put it into the shell:startup and everytime I turn my computer on it will do it automatically for me.

Thank you so much in advance.

Edit:

I'm sorry I wasn't aware of that. This is the error I get:

> C:\Users\borah>C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe
> "$Process = Get-Process audiodg.exe; $Process.ProcessorAffinity=1"
> Get-Process : Cannot find a process with the name "audiodg.exe".
> Verify the process name and call the cmdlet again. At line:1 char:12
>
> - $Process = Get-Process audiodg.exe; $Process.ProcessorAffinity=1
> - ```
>          ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>   ```
>
>   - CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (audiodg.exe:String) [Get-Process], ProcessCommandException
>   - FullyQualifiedErrorId : NoProcessFoundForGivenName,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GetProcessCommand
>
> The property 'ProcessorAffinity' cannot be found on this object.
> Verify that the property exists and can be set. At line:1 char:37
>
> - $Process = Get-Process audiodg.exe; $Process.ProcessorAffinity=1
> - ```
>                                   ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>   ```
>
>   - CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [], RuntimeException
>   - FullyQualifiedErrorId : PropertyNotFound

Comment: So you need to create in startup folder just a shortcut file with `C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe "$Process = Get-Process audiodg.exe; $Process.ProcessorAffinity=1"` for property __Target__.

Answer (score 2):

You can set affinity by typing a command, like following,

```
Start /affinity 2 notepad
```

This will start notepad while setting an affinity to second core of CPU.

[image]

You can save the command above in a file ending with .cmd and run it by double clicking like any other application. Or you can use task scheduler to launch it with windows startup every time, or you can run it as a startup application.

**Edit**

If you meant changing affinity of an already running process. Check Mofi's comment as solution.

```
C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe "$Process = Get-Process audiodg; $Process.ProcessorAffinity=1"
```

Comment: That worked perfectly. Thank you so much! Just one last thing. I saved this as a bat file but in order for the code to work, the bat file needs to be opened with administration rights. How do I set it up to do that on the startup ?

Comment: @BorahanGülpınar the easiest solution probably is to create a shortcut of your bat file then `Right click script.bat shortcut -> Properties -> Shortcut tab -> Advanced... -> Run as Administrator.` That will always launch the script as administrator.